# downloads not started

Tags: downloading, android-10, pdf

I have just got a new android 10 tablet and I'm having a really stupid user interface problem.

When I click a link to a PDF document in the web browswer (Chrome) I click download and nothing happens.
After much routing around I eventually found the downloads listed in the new "google go" app.
This lists my downloads as "downloaded not started" once for each time I clicked it.

There is no obvious way to start the downloads from here.

This is very stupid default behaviour. **How do I change it?**

I read around somewhere that I needed to:

- install a pdf viewer app - done
- change the file associations  (in settings/apps & notifications/default apps)

There is no file association for PDF and no (obvious) way to add a new one
I just have:

- Assist App   - Google Assistant Go
- Browser App  - Chrome
- Home App     - Quickstep
- Phone app    - phone
- SMS app      - message
- <blank>    - opening links

I select a PDF viewer (e.g. Adobe) and try to enable "open by default". Nothing happens.

I did actually get some PDFs to download and thought I had fixed the problem but the next time I tried it happened again.

What am I doing wrong?
I find it hard to believe Google can have so thoroughly broken something as basic as this. So what am I missing?

What I expect:

- I should be able to download arbitrary files to an arbitrary location
  (after clicking that I accept the risk if fine)
- Something should tell me where the files were downloaded to without having to search the internet for an answer.
- PDF files should open either in the browser directly or from a 'downloads tab'
- The "go" app should have a button somewhere to let me start the downloads

How do I make this happen?

Are the "google Go" and "google files" apps the problem? Can I/ Should I replace them with something more intuitive.

The tablet is something model is listed as "Q3".

Comment: Maybe try a download manager like this, which is well rated and claims to select download location https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dv.adm